# Purpose of each disk access and why it may not occur

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I'm going over past papers for an exam I have and my university do not provide answers so that I can check them, please could you let me know if my understanding is correct and if not please could you correct it.

**Question:** A program P running on a Linux system takes the name and path of a file on disk containing text as an argument; it opens the file and reads the first character from it. Assuming the program is already running and the file exists, list the disk read requests that could occur, describing:

• The purpose of each disk access.

• Why the disk read request might not always occur.

**Attempt:** A disk read request might not always occur because a cache hit may occur and so the file can be read from cache without a disk read request. If this does not happen disk accesses will occur. One to get the file's name, another to get the path of the file and the final one to read the first character from the file

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I'm asking if someone could provide me with an answer to the question listed above. I've copied the question word for word from the exam paper so their is no details missing. I have also provided my attempt at the question so that someone may correct my understanding if it is wrong rather than just providing me with the answer. @TD.512

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting at least one disk access: The directory entry of the file has an `access time`, so each read, even though the file itself is in the cache, means the directory has to be updated.

But, to be honest, this question cannot be answered easily, without knowing a lot of pre-conditions. The 'possible' disk accesses depend on many factors, probably the most important one is the size of the file.